# comparing time in an if clause

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am dealing with a large financial datasset (> 15gb) and trying to get (write to a CSV file) the quotes 30 mins before and after an announcement time. specifically, I will have 2 CSV files, 1 containing quotes data and 1 containing earning announcement timestamps. I have tried my codes as below:

```
import datetime
import csv

df1 = csv.DictReader(open('earning_announcements.csv'))
df2 = csv.DictReader(open('quote_data.csv'))

data_writer = csv.DictWriter(open('quotes_selected.csv', 'wb'), fieldnames=['RIC', 'Date[L]', 'Time[L]','Close Bid', 'No. Bids','Close Ask', 'No. Asks'])
data_writer.writeheader()

for row2 in df2:
    for row1 in df1:
        if (row2['RIC'][:3] == row1['RIC'] and 
            row2['Time'] < row1['Time'] and 
            (row2['Time'] >= (row1['Time']- datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)))):
            data_writer.writerow(row2)
```

my earning_announcement.csv(df1) looks like this (other columns have been neglected):

```
RIC Date        Time
ACR 23-08-12    16:26:00
ACR 23-08-12    16:22:00
AEJ 25-02-11    15:34:00
AEJ 31-08-11    15:39:00
AEJ 29-02-12    16:10:00
AEJ 31-08-12    16:08:00
AFI 25-07-11    10:43:00
```

and the quote_data.csv (df2) looks like this:

```
RIC Date        Time    Close Bid   No. Bids    Close Ask   No. Asks
ACR 20120823    15:52:00    3.89    0            3.9         0
ACR 20120823    15:52:05    3.89    0            3.9         0
ACR 20120823    15:52:10    3.89    1            3.9         0
ACR 20120823    15:52:15    3.89    0            3.9         0
ACR 20120823    15:52:20    3.89    0            3.9         1
ACR 20120823    15:52:25    3.89    0            3.9         1
ACR 20120823    15:52:30    3.89    5            3.9         0
ACR 20120823    15:52:35    3.89    0            3.9         0
ACR 20120823    15:52:40    3.88    17           3.89        6
ACR 20120823    15:52:45    3.88    3            3.89        7
```

note: RIC is stock code
I also want to classify whether it is before or after the announcement timestamps (i.e. create a column that say before/after) but dont know how.
Can you guys please help me. I really appreciate it and sorry if my codes are too confusing.
Thank you so much.

Comment: can you add the samples from the file?

Comment: @VedangMehta I have fixed some silly errors and provided a sample of the datasets. However this time it only prints the headers, not the rows I want :-( Please help. Thank you very much

Comment: What if time difference if below 30 minutes, but dates are different? You didn't consider that in your code.

Comment: date differences are fine. I need to get the quotes during a specific time period for all the dates i.e. if company ABC announced a news at 2pm, I want to get the quotes from 1:30pm to 2:30 pm for everyday.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible source of problems in your code:

1. variable **row** is referred but not initialized
2. IMHO **df1** reader should be reopened in every iteration of the outer loop

Comment: sorry if I am wrong as I am new to Python but row is a variable used in the loop ( can be name x, y or i and it does the same thing). I have tested (try to print out the column) and it looks like df1 reader does not need to be reopened in every iteration. Please help me if there is a more efficient way to read csv. My main dataset is very large (>200gb) so I need to read the csv line by line and iterate through each line and keep only the ones I need.

Comment: I sort of see what you mean now. I have to declare df1 before the loop. is there a way to store my df1 into an array?

Comment: Given that your dataset is 15Gb I would like to avoid loading it into the memory if I were you. Loading it to some database management system may help (or not). Such systems are optimized to perform operations you are going to do. Also, you may optimize your algorithm by splitting the files by the RIC field first. If records in the files are sorted, you may iterate over one file and use double-ended queue to cache rows of the other file from relevant period of time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are few silly mistakes in the code. As it is mentioned already, you have not initialized 'row' or may you have misspelled 'row1' as 'row'.

You have mentioned in your question subject as 'comparing time in an if clause' but you are assigning the value in the first logic within if. Refer to the documentation of basic operators [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm).

And also at the end you are comparing values of the same row, not sure whether it is intentional.

Comment: I have fixed the errors. in the if clause, I want to compare values of each row in different datasets against each other. i.e. I compare the Time column of row2 from the quote_data(df2) against the Time column of row1 from the earning_announcement data.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mention a data set > 15Gb but in one of your comments you refer to a data set of 200 Gb, whichever it is, reading through a csv file is not the way to attempt this task.
Load the data sets into a database and process that.
That will also allow you to pre-select what data is relevant and what is not.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide a way to do that? and what do you mean by load the dataset into a database? wouldn't it too much for memory (RAM). my main dataset will be around 200gb but the one I am playing with in python is only 15gb.

Comment: There are a plethora of relational databases available. Sqlite3 being my favourite but I suspect with data sets as large as yours you need something like MySql or PostgreSql. Load the csv file into the database, then you can access the data as individual records. Endlessly reading and re-reading a csv file, over and over again, especially of this size, is about the most inefficient way of performing the task, possible!

Comment: http://halfcooked.com/presentations/osdc2006/python_databases.html https://www.fullstackpython.com/databases.html